# React element keeps rerendering without changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've recently picked up React and I'm trying to build a simple app to learn it. Now, If I'm not mistaken, React should re-render every time i call setState or there is some change in the props. However, when I run my code with a console.log inside, my console gets flooded by logs, like 10 each second. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to avoid this?

This is function that calls the log:

```
function SingleCountry(props) {
    const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState("");

    const populateCountries = props.countries.map((elem, i) => {
        return (<option key={i}>{elem.country}</option>)
    });
    const findCountry = props.countries.filter((elem) => {
        return elem.country === selectedCountry;
    });

    console.log(findCountry);

    return (
        <>
        <div>
            <Form>
                <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="test">
                <Form.Control as="select" value="Selected Country..." 
                 onChange={e => setSelectedCountry(e.target.value)}>
                    <option>Select Country...</option>
                    {populateCountries}
                </Form.Control>
                </Form.Group>
            </Form>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>TODO: Print selected country...</p>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

... and this is the parent function

```
function Home() {
    const [worldData, setWorldData] = useState();
    const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);


    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.all([
            Axios.get("https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/all"),
            Axios.get("https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries"),
        ])
        .then((response) => {
            setWorldData(response[0].data);
            setCountries(response[1].data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        })

    }, [worldData, countries]);

    return (
       <div>
           {loading === true && (
               <Loading />
           )}
           {loading === false && (
               <>
               <WorldData data={worldData} />
               <SingleCountry countries={countries} />
               </>
           )}
       </div>
    );
}
```

When I launch the Home from App.js, my console ends up like this

[Image of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0IJa.png)

and it keeps spamming the log.

EDIT: The Image I posted is actually the console log after I select something from the select dropdown, that's why there's something inside but the log still fires even before I do anything. It's not really important but just to be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of the way you are handling `useEffect` every time you receive worlddata and countries the state changes because you are setting it, but since in your dependencies of useEffect you have given it worlddata and countries it gonna rerun. Meaning it will fetch them again and again. Try this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        Axios.all([
            Axios.get("https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/all"),
            Axios.get("https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries"),
        ])
        .then((response) => {
            setWorldData(response[0].data);
            setCountries(response[1].data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        })

    }, []);
```

Empty array means it will only run once on component mount.

Comment: I misunderstood how the second argument of useEffect works. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: if it helped would you consider accepting the answer? you're new here i see the checkmark next to the question click to accept so others would know this helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

From your posted code I would guess you should also see the Axios fetches over and over again. The problem i the `useEffect` and it's listening objects inside `Home`.  It will run the fetch calls everytime either `worldData` or `countries` are changing. So you're setting the `worldData` inside this function, on which it's listening, so it's recalling itself. Change the listeners to `setWorldData` and `setCountries` and the fetch and rendering should work as expected.

Comment: Oh I see, so I ended up creating a loop. Thanks for the explanation!